# How get post id from meta value

Tags: post-meta

Please look at the picture below. I want to get `post_id` from `meta_value` = **93**. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116419/mysql-select-query-within-a-serialized-array

Comment: I have do this and it's working now :
`global $wpdb;
  $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_id FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wbs_crosssells' && meta_value like '%%%s%%'",serialize($product_id));
  $res = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, OBJECT );

  return $res;`

Comment: Just keep in mind it's not a recommended method and queries may run slowly, potentially causing site stability issues. Glad you found a solution though.

Comment: Use meta API, it's cached and optimized `$meta = get_post_meta(96, '_wbs_crosssells', true);`

Answer (score 7):

Try this. It will work.

```
$prepare_guery = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdp->posts where meta_key ='_Wps_crossells' and meta_value like '%%d%'", $meta_value );
$get_values = $wpdb->get_col( $prepare_guery );
```

**Let me know it's working or not.**

Comment: yes . It's working now, same my comment above

Comment: okk. then fine.

Comment: You mean `FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE`.

Answer (score 5):

```
global $wpdb;

$tbl = $wpdb->prefix.'postmeta';

$prepare_guery = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_id FROM $tbl where meta_key ='_Wps_crossells' and meta_value like '%%d%'", $meta_value );

$get_values = $wpdb->get_col( $prepare_guery );
```

**Note:** Table Should be `$wpdb->prefix.'postmeta';`

Comment: It should be a comment on another answer. When you get 50 reputation points you will be able to comment on any posts.